# A dearth of sea

Tags: riddle, mathematics, steganography

> I'M thinkng of a fuction
>   hat continus increasin without limit
>   the ES itS domain
>
> IT has a Rang lacking diSjunctioN
>   which cannot acint with
>   is dismal lowr lane
>
> Through ELiinG and xpunction
>   you may arive ye at it
>   f you don't orthink.

Comment: @ArkaKarmakar just post your own answer then, instead of commenting on everyone else's? I'm curious how that's trivial, because I thought of that phrase also but didn't see how to make it work.

Comment: @whrrgarbl: When you see integral e__ derivative, and it's not an Math stackexchange site, there is a huge probably it is something to do with equal, so I guessed it and took the chance. And I have a bad rep in answering, so it might get downvoted if it is a red herring.

Comment: @Strawberry: Who ?

Comment: @ArkaKarmakar where do you see "derivative"? I agree the first two are easy to find, but that's where I got stuck.

Comment: @whrrgarbl: Random educated guessing. I was guessing, and I am bad at it, so I posted a comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible answer:

> $f(n)$ $=$ $e$<sup>$n$</sup> 
>  the [Exponential Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function)
> Others have pointed out that 'A Dearth at Sea' means to leave out any [constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(mathematics))

The Capitals spell out

> IMESSITRSNTELG

Which @JonathanAllan has found is an anagram of

> MISSING LETTERS

So we need to focus on the missing letters

There are also some letters that are missing from the riddle though it is hard to make out the intended words...

I think the riddle is trying to say:

> I'M think**i**ng of a fu**n**ction
> **t**hat continu**e**s increasin**g** without limit
> the **r**E**al**S itS domain (Thanks @DanRussell)
>
> IT has a Rang**e** lacking diSjunctioN
> which cannot ac**qua**int with
> i**t**s dismal low**e**r lane**s**
>
> Through ELi**d**inG and **e**xpunction
> you may ar**r**ive ye**t** at it
> **i**f you don't o**ve**rthink.

So so far the missing letters are:

> **integral equates der?ive (derivative?)**

Comment: Letters missing.

Comment: @ArkaKarmakar, it will be difficult to fit "iva" between the "r" and "t" of "arrive" and "yet"...

Comment: @IanMacDonald: See Dan Russel's answer.

Comment: @ArkaKarmakar, Dan Russel's answer posits "derivative" using the letters "dertive". It is missing the "iva", as I suggested.

Comment: @IanMacDonald: Oh, yeah, you are right. I didn't read it mindfully.

Answer (score 8):

Most likely

> The function you are thinking of is $f(x) = e^{x}$, the exponential function.
>  The title clue is "A dearth of sea", so no $+c$, no constant added.

The

> capitals are an anagram of MISSING LETTERS

So we should look at them...

> I think they are: **INTEGRAL EQUATE DERIVE**:
>
> i'm think**I**ng of a fu**N**ction
> **T**hat continu**E**s increasin**G** without limit
> the **R**e**AL**s **ARE** its domain
>
> it has a rang**E** lacking disjunction
> which cannot ac**QUA**int with
> i**T**s dismal low**E**r lane
>
> through eli**D**ing and **E**xpunction
> you may ar**R**ive ye at it
> **I**f you don't o**VE**rthink.

Comment: Oh wait, there is no "S" for that first word...

Comment: And the T at the start of th last para is already there too

Answer (score 7):

The final answer is probably

> $y=e^x$, because its integral equals its derivative.
>
>  (N.B. that the title's "death of sea" means to leave out any constant $C$ to ensure this is true.)

As pointed out by others, the capital letters

> are an anagram of "MISSING LETTERS".

I think all the missing letters from the first paragraph spell

> **integral**
>
>  I'M think(i)ng of a fu(n)ction
>  (t)hat continu(e)s increasin(g) without limit
>  the (r)E(al)S itS domain

The second paragraph

> **equates**
>
>  IT has a Rang(e) lacking diSjunctioN
>  which cannot ac(qua)int with
>  i(t)s dismal low(e)r lane(s)

A possiblity for the third paragraph is

> **derivative**?
>
>  Through ELi(d)inG and (e)xpunction
>  you may ar(r)ive ye(t) at it
>  (i)f you don't o(ve)rthink.

Comment: OK almost the same as my answer :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ah, yes.  All working on it in parallel apparently!

Comment: I'm sticking with the olde English "You may arrive ye at it" :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Which I like, but I remember my calculus teacher from high school: "*differentiate*, not derive!"

Answer (score 5):

Another try:

> Missing letters (anagram credit to Jonathan Allen!) in parentheses:
>
>  I'M think(i)ng of a fu(n)ction
>  (t)hat continu(e)s increasin(g) without limit
>  the (r)E(al)S itS domain
>
>  IT has a Rang(e) lacking diSjunctioN
>  which cannot ac(qua)int with
>  i(t)s dismal low(e)r lane
>
>  Through ELi(d)inG and (e)xpunction
>  you may a(r)rive ye at it *(yet?)*
>  (i)f you don't o(ve)rthink.

This gives the words:

> integral, equate, derive

Title refers to:

> The constant of integration (typically `+ C`)